# Copy Constructor and UniformInitalization list

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11

```
struct FileResource {



    explicit FileResource(HANDLE hFile) : _hFile{ hFile }   {
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            Close();
        }
    }



    auto Close() -> void {
        if (_hFile) {
            CloseHandle(_hFile);
        }
    }

    ~FileResource() {
        Close();
    }

    explicit operator bool() const {
        return _hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    auto get() -> HANDLE {
        return _hFile;
    }


    FileResource(const FileResource &) = delete;
    auto operator=(const FileResource &) -> FileResource& = delete;



private:
    HANDLE _hFile;

};

auto hFile = FileResource{
        CreateFile(fileName1, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr)
    };
```

i trying to make a smart class, so i had deleted the copy constructor, 
but using the uniform initialization syntax i'm unable to construct it;
below example works

HANDLE h;
FileResource {h};

any clues;

Comment: I'm confused. That code works, or it doesn't work? Which outcome did you expect, and which outcome did you want?

Comment: compiler says it cannot access the copy constructor but i'm not passing FileResource object i'm passing HANDLE which should call the normal construcotr

Comment: `auto hFile = FileResource{` yes you are.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do all the work! Instead, use the **[Rule Of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)**:

```
struct FileResource 
{
    explicit FileResource(HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        : _hFile(hFile, &::CloseHandle) { }
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::CloseHandle)> _hFile;
};
```

You can use it just like you wanted:

```
int main()
{
    auto hFile = FileResource {
        CreateFile("main.cpp", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr)
    };
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c33209d2192e7fa3)**

Comment: All hail the Rule of Zero!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you can not do following?

```
FileResource f = {h};
```

If yes then it is because you deleted FileResource copy constructor. {h} is inteprested as consturcting a temporary struct FileResource then use copy constructor to initalize f. if you insists, you should use: `FileResource f =h`

Comment: HANDLE someHandle;
auto fh = FileResource{someHandle} //this works
auto fh1 = FileResource{ CreateFile() } //doesn't work